# Changing the routes for named parameters in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following two routes which make the url `/posts/recent` show page 1 of the recent filter on index method of my posts controller and also allow paging like: `/posts/recent/page:2` by using the * on the next route. As you can see I call page 1 on the first route so that I don't get duplicate urls for page 1.

```
Router::connect('/posts/recent', array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'index','filter'=>'recent', 'page' => 1), array('pass'=>array('filter')));


Router::connect('/posts/recent/*', array(
  'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index', 'filter'=>'recent'), array(
    'named' =>array('page' => '[\d]+'),
     'pass'=>array('filter')
  )
);
```

However I would like to make it so that named params do this instead:

`/posts/recent/page/2` but how do I do it?

I've looked around the docs but don't seem to see anything about doing this...

Also is it possible to turn off named parameters in favour of query strings?

I'm using CakePHP 2.1 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with Router::connectNamed()?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: What does that do? As from the docs it looks like it just adds the named parameter to the route which is what it's already doing automatically... am I misunderstanding?